# how I can redirect visitors from my old domain to new domain on the same page?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I just transferred my site to new domain and I want to redirect visitors on old domain to new domain on the same page.
For example:
If someone visit www.myolddomain.com/123.html
It should redirect him to the
www.mynewdomain.com/123.html

How I can do that?
My all code is in PHP
Does it require use of .htaccess with rewrite rule?
I have this rewrite rule on my old domain
    
    `RewriteRule (.*).html$ /real.php?id=$1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) would be easier. For the virtual host config for www.myolddomain.com

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.mynewdomain.com/
```

Comment: I want to redirect it on the same page like when user click on www.myolddomain.com/123.html it redirect him to mynewdomain.com/123.html not only to mynewdomain.com

Comment: @Badal — Read the link. Try the config. **That is what that does**

Answer (score 0):

The natural way to do this is change entry in DNS.

Answer (score 0):

simples of that is Jquery
$(window).load(
    function() {window.location = "http://newdomain.com/";});